# asp.net Internet Explorer window focus glitch

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I am experiencing a weird glitch with an asp.net site and Internet Explorer. Any time the site posts back the IE window will get moved to the background. Has anyone else noticed this before? I have no idea where to start looking to track this down.

Some observations:

- Does not occur in FireFox
- Does not occur in other asp.net sites on the same machine even in IE
- Was noticed by a client on multiple computers and replicated by me on a dev machine
- The glitch is not noticeable if there are no other windows on the screen i.e. if there is nothing that could cover up the IE window
- Looking at my alt-tab list after the glitch occurs the IE window has been moved to the end of the cycle

Comment: Interesting. Could you make a screen-capture video, so we can see the behavior?

Comment: I guess I could but what is confusing about my description? It seems like the window is losing focus and being moved to the end of the window cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track this down. It seems the cause is a javascript date picker I'm using.